# Classifying groups of order $pq$, $p<q$, using semi direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be any group of order $pq$, where $p < q$.

Consider the case where $p \mid q-1$ and let $P = \langle y \rangle$. Since $Aut(Q)$ is cyclic it contains a unique subgroup of order $p$, say $ \langle \gamma \rangle$, and any homomorphism $\phi: P \to Aut(Q)$  must map $y$ to a power of $\gamma$. (I am not able to prove to myself this statement).

Why must any element of $P$ be mapped to the subgroup, $\langle \gamma \rangle$ of $Aut(Q)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to map your $P$ onto a cyclic subgroup of order $p$ of $Aut(Q)$, so you can map it on $\langle \gamma \rangle$ . Now any homomorphism from $P=\langle y \rangle$, say $\phi$, will satisfy that $\phi(P) \le Aut(Q)$ so order of $\phi(P)\ |\ q-1$  and let $\phi(P)=\langle t \rangle$ then $o(t)\ |\ p$ and thus if $\phi$ is non trivial then $\phi(P)= \langle \gamma \rangle$

Now take $\phi(y)$ to some element of  $\langle \gamma \rangle$  but all elements are powers of $\gamma$. But to be an isomorphism, $y \to \gamma^i$ such that $(i,p)=1$ (Verify!)

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that the image of $P$ would need to have order $p$ since homomorphisms do not necessarily preserve order. I only know that the subgroup, $\phi(P)$ of $Aut(Q)$ would need to divide $q-1$. Since $p \mid q-1$, the subgroup $\langle \gamma \rangle$ is reasonable choice, but why is this the only choice?

Comment: wait,  I am editing

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.